# yii2 call controller action from view and debug process

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, controller, yii2

In a datagrid view I have a textinput field and I want to call a controller function if the field gets updated. Therfore I included a script into my form and prepared a controller function.

```
$this->registerJs(
    "$('#product_qty').on('click', function() { 
        alert('Button clicked!'); 
        $.ajax({
            url: '".Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/suppliers_orders/changequantity' . "',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                 id: '5' , 
                 _csrf : '" . Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken() . "'
             },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.search);
                },
            });
    });",
    \yii\web\View::POS_READY,
    'my-button-handler'
);
```

The alert function will be called and shows 'Button clicked'. Then nothing happens.

The controller of Suppliers_orderController function is:

```
public function actionChangequantity(){

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
            $id = $data['id'];
        }
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return [
            'search' => $id,
        ];
}
```

Furthermore I want to trace the activity with phpstorm and xdebug, but the debug process don't stop at the first breakpoint in the controller. What is missing, or is my JS function wrong?

Comment: have you tried adding `console.log("hello word!")` inside the `click` event binding to see if it is entering or not, check for dual id's by typing in console `$("#product_qty").length` what does it output 1, 2 or 0. also you should use `error` too is you are using `success` in case there is some error in request you wont know it, add a `console.log("error")` inside the error callback function.

Comment: Hello Muhammed, nice to see you again! ;-) In the Browser Console I can see that there is an Error 404 (Not Found). The Url which is displayed seems to be wrong,  /backend/web/suppliers_orders/changequantity! Usually after /web there is the /controllers folder in the file structure. But also /backend/web/controllers/suppliers_orders/changequantity ends with 404 (Not Found)!

Comment: added an answer see if that helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above all, in `Yii2` you have `\yii\helpers\Url::base();` to get the baseurl rather than `Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;` that is the reason of wrong url printing in the console without the baseUrl, so change your line

```
url: '".Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/suppliers_orders/changequantity' . "',
```

to the following

```
url: '".\yii\helpers\Url::base(). '/suppliers_orders/changequantity' . "',
```

Secondly, if you are using localhost path instead of virtual hosts for the `frontend` and `backend` and for accessing the `controller/action` you have to use `index.php` along with the path after `web` like below

`http://localhost/myproject/backend/web/index.php/suppliers_orders/changequantity`

Comment: url: '".\yii\helpers\Url::base(). '/suppliers_orders/changequantity' . "' is exactly solving the problem! Thx, Muhammad!